Errors/artifacts when opening ggplot2 SVG in Inkscape
I have a script which saves creates a simple plot in ggplot2 and saves it as an SVG:
library(ggplot2)

x <- seq(1, 20, length.out = 1000)
y <- sin(x)

df <- data.frame(x=x, y=y)

ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_line()

ggsave('test.svg', width=5, height=5)

Looks good in RStudio:

I then make a new Inkscape document and drag in my new SVG.  I select "Include SVG image as editable object(s)" in the current file.  The loaded image has massive artifacts:

I can instead select "Embed the SVG file as an image tag", but then I lose the ability to edit parts of the image.   It also seems to lock the image to a specific DPI.  I'd prefer to get the content loaded as an editable SVG.
I've seen some related posts, but nothing with artifacts like what I am seeing, and nothing that has helped me solve the issue yet:

R & Inkscape: text labels in SVG graphics exported from R did not recognized as a text in Inkscape
ggplot PDF import to Inkscape adds extra hollow circles to geom_point dots when using alpha
How to preserve text when saving ggplot2 as .svg?

I might be missing something obvious, as Inkscape (and general image editing) is new to me.  Let me know if you have any ideas, thanks!

There is nothing wrong with the svg file, Inkscape is doing something weird when dragging files into your drawing. Open the file directly and it should look as intended.

presumably the SVG is using CSS. Perhaps it's https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/105884/managing-styles-with-css-classes-in-inkscape or something else about the CSS.

@teunbrand Yes, opening directly seems to work.  But let's say I want to add the image to an existing document?  I'm trying to make multi-panel figures in Inkscape, so I need to arrange multiple SVGs.  Based on your suggestion, I have found that I can open the SVG directly and then copy/paste it into another Inkscape document.  So that is a workaround, but is a little clumsy.  Again, maybe I'm just missing some basic inkscape function but not sure

@RobertLongson Thanks for the suggestion!  Not too familiar with CSS, but I will see if I get anywhere based on this post

Finally found a similar error: https://inkscape.org/forums/questions/line-stroke-gets-invisible-upon-svg-drag-and-drop-import/ (thanks to teunbrand for good hint).  There's a potential explanation from Paddy_CAD there.  But bottom line still seems that you have to open directly at some point, rather than importing/drag & dropping

The graph needs to have fill="none" - otherwise it is filled with black (what happened in 2. inkscape screenshot).  I bet the ggplot svg has applied fill="none" to the parent svg. So when dragging the graphic to the new element this property gets lost. You could also change the fill to none manually but open the file directly is certainly easier
